# FB bot doesn't sent messages in live mode

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots

I'm writting fb bot. I cann't to get messages in my webhook in live mode. So fb bot works right just in developer mode.

When I click on Test button, it sends test messages to my webhook. gyazo.com/b9cd4a3046cd258b508706ddab13c9ec E.g. when I click on Test (where is feed) it sends test feeds to my webhooks.

Should get messages in webhooks in live mode as well when I click on Post button on my Page and then click Share.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to Page events like "feed" that's the expected behavior and by design since apps in dev mode don't deliver events and your app needs to be live and reviewed to receive them.

Comment: Thank you. Should I pass all verification as well?

Comment: It's a little bit unclear what you actually refer to, because you say "bot", but also "feed". A Messenger Platform bot integration can be fully tested in dev mode and using your own admin user, a page feed event on the other hand requires your app to be live (and approved) to receive real events/data.

Comment: Generally, I need that all I type in Post box, falls in my webhook. Now I sticked here https://gyazo.com/bc011f1a06777418728a9b0ab7d6ea40 because don't have own domain.